# How to do post-processing to headers/buffer in Zend's MVC?

Tags: php, zend-framework, output-buffering

So, I have created a Zend application following the quick start guide (so it has layouts, and heavy usage of application.ini configurations rather that hard-coded options) with a few changes here and there, but now I want to manipulate the output given to the browser... I've googled but it seems that I don't know how to search or more importantly what to search... I want to be able to do something like:

```
<?php

    ob_start();

    echo 'Hello ';
    echo 'World';
    echo '!';

    $buffer = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    echo my_own_function($buffer);

?>
```

And do some TIDY, comment/space removing, etc... I mean it isn't just that, I want to be able to do any post-processing **on-the-fly**. Also I wanna get my hands over the headers before are dispatched (I'm using php5.3) it is possible?

I mean which are the classes/methods that output headers and send text to the browser so it can be interpreted?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this purpose you can write a Zend_Controller plugin.
See the documentation here: [Zend Controller Plugins](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.plugins.html).

In your particular situation, you want to hook on the **dispatchLoopShutdown** method.

How to write these plugins is described on the linked page.

Comment: Thanks, it's seems that Zend has much to offer... I just hope don't get overwhelmed by it... with your comment I found the full solution here, with almost everything I thought http://devzone.zend.com/article/3372-Front-Controller-Plugins-in-Zend-Framework